# Can cloudformation upsert a route53 record for me?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-route53

I want to manage a route53 records with cloudformation

I want to be able to change the valute of a record in the cf template and have it update (UPSERT) the record: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/APIReference/API_ChangeResourceRecordSets.html

Will AWS::Route53::RecordSetGroup correctly update the record by performing an UPSERT?
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-route53-recordsetgroup.html